# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24 Incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

All... based on another question I've posted here recently, I built this stored procedure, but when executed, I receive the error in the title.

As you can see, I tried to remove any aliases, but it didn't matter. Not sure how to use PRINT to see the issue on this either. Of course the isolated `SELECT` statement works on its own.

I can even pull results from my temp table after the error appears. So is it a problem in this script or the results? Appreciate your assistance. I also only used the WHERE statement to limit the test results.

```
    ALTER PROC ap_vhdr_test AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('temp.dbo.#ap_vend_det') is NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ap_vend_det;

CREATE TABLE #ap_vend_det           
(db_name varchar(32)
, vendor_name varchar(40)
, vendor_code varchar(12)
, voucher_no varchar(16)
, invoice_num varchar(16)
, inv_date varchar(16)
, due_date varchar(16)
, apply_date varchar(16)
, total float
, line_desc varchar(40)
, company_id smallint
, gl_num varchar(32)
, acct_site varchar(32)
, sort_code varchar(32)
, nat_gl varchar(32)
, gl_desc varchar(40)
, category nvarchar(510)
, sub_category nvarchar(510)
, po_num varchar(16)
, vendor_class varchar(8)
)
INSERT INTO #ap_vend_det
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'IF ''?'' NOT IN ( ''model'',''tempdb'',''master'',''msdb'')
BEGIN SELECT DISTINCT db_name = ''?''
, amaster.addr1 --as vendor_name
, amaster.vendor_code --as vendor_code
, apdet.trx_ctrl_num --as voucher_no
, aphdr.doc_ctrl_num --as invoice_num
, CONVERT(varchar(16),dateadd(dd,(aphdr.date_doc - 639906),''1/1/1753''),101) --as inv_date 
, CONVERT(varchar(16),dateadd(dd,(aphdr.date_due - 639906),''1/1/1753''),101) --as due_date
, CONVERT(varchar(16),dateadd(dd,(aphdr.date_applied - 639906),''1/1/1753''),101) --as apply_date
, aphdr.amt_net --as total
, aphdr.doc_desc --as line_desc
, gldet.company_id --as company_id
, gldet.account_code --as gl_num
, gldet.seg2_code --as acct_site
, gldet.seg3_code --as sort_code
, gldet.seg1_code --as nat_gl
, gldet.description --as gl_desc
, ap_coa.group_header --as category
, ap_coa.group_label  --as sub_category
, apdet.po_ctrl_num --as po_num
, apvend.vend_class_code --as vendor_class
FROM ?.dbo.amaster --amaster
JOIN ?.dbo.aphdr --aphdr                        --**
    ON amaster.vendor_code = aphdr.vendor_code
    AND amaster.pay_to_code = aphdr.pay_to_code
JOIN ?.dbo.apdet --apdet
    ON aphdr.trx_ctrl_num = apdet.trx_ctrl_num
JOIN ?.dbo.gldet --gldet
    ON aphdr.journal_ctrl_num = gldet.journal_ctrl_num
JOIN ?.dbo.glt --glt
    ON gldet.journal_ctrl_num = glt.journal_ctrl_num
JOIN ?.dbo.apvend --apvend
    ON amaster.vendor_code = apvend.vendor_code
JOIN reps.dbo.ap_coa --ap_coa
    ON gldet.seg1_code = ap_coa.acct_code
WHERE aphdr.date_applied >= ''734785''              
END';

SELECT * FROM #ap_vend_det;
```

Comment: Stop, stop, stop using sp_MSforeachdb. It's unsupported and undocumented for a reason! Not only does it not handle databases with special characters, sometimes it just skips databases altogether. Please see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx and http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fail if you have database names that have spaces or other characters in them.  You need to enclose them in square brackets, e.g.

```
FROM [?].dbo.amaster --amaster
```

Not only that, because you are using 3 part names, you also need to alias the tables in the FROM clause.

```
FROM [?].dbo.amaster amaster
JOIN [?].dbo.aphdr aphdr                        --**
    ON amaster.vendor_code = aphdr.vendor_code
    AND amaster.pay_to_code = aphdr.pay_to_code
JOIN [?].dbo.apdet apdet
    ON aphdr.trx_ctrl_num = apdet.trx_ctrl_num
JOIN [?].dbo.gldet gldet
    ON aphdr.journal_ctrl_num = gldet.journal_ctrl_num
JOIN [?].dbo.glt glt
    ON gldet.journal_ctrl_num = glt.journal_ctrl_num
JOIN [?].dbo.apvend apvend
    ON amaster.vendor_code = apvend.vendor_code
JOIN reps.dbo.ap_coa ap_coa
    ON gldet.seg1_code = ap_coa.acct_code
WHERE aphdr.date_applied >= ''734785''
```

Comment: Thanks.  The only other character used is underscore in the db names. I enclosed the ? in brackets [?], readded the aliases and... (waiting on results and for dramatic affect)